# Is it possible to globally include headers in a fetch request?

Tags: javascript

I have the following

```
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': localStorage.id_token
        },
    };
    fetch(`${API_ROOT}/somepathfoo`, requestOptions)
```

And I was wondering if it was possible to hook into the fetch request and ensure to include the headers across all my fetch calls instead of me manually adding them. There are calls where the method is PATCH or PUT or DELETE, etc but I always want the Authorization header to be included.

Comment: Put your headers in a variable, and use that in all your calls.

Comment: Write your own fetch function wrapper

Comment: You *don't* want to include these headers in *all* `fetch` calls. You want them only in requests to your own backend. Setting up global configuration would prevent you from using third-party libraries with third-party APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Write a wrapper to fetch which adds the desired headers and use that function when needed:

```
function authorizedFetch(url, options) {
  if (!options) { options = {} }
  if (!options.headers) { options.headers = {} }
  if (!options.headers.Authorization) {
    options.headers.Authorization = localStorage.id_token
  }
  return fetch(url, options)
}

// ...
authorizedFetch(`${API_ROOT}/somepathfoo`)
```